# how to transffer data from website to android app and enable or disable it from website only?

Tags: php, android, wordpress

My team is  going to make application in android having quizzes on mobile whose questions,options would be entered from my website. I want to be able to enable the new quiz from website end. 
Going to code website in PHP. I'm good at wordpress so just wondering if I can do this in that only or not as I don't in what form I have to convert my data so that android can get it and use it in "native app"(not browser!!).

my job is only the website part I know how to make pages but don't know in what form I have to give quiz data and how to control enabling and disabling the quiz in mobile app

thanks for the help in advance...

Comment: Only your team would be able to tell you what form to provide the data. If they don't know then your project has a vanishingly small chance of success.

Comment: They Have given two options JSON and XML..
in JSON I can just transfer this in form of Array as much as I've read from..
But I'm thinking more of XML.Searching on it now only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have to be done in PHP(EDIT: or any other technology as such) since your team is working in PHP already. To enable/disable the "new quiz", the app would have to query the server for this information, which would come from the Database.

Comment: Can you explain in bit more detail?
That would be more appreciable.. :)

Comment: It dosen't have to be done in PHP - there are other server technologies that could do this. This is not an answer: it could possibly be a comment.

Comment: The Android app, would have to use a webservice. Lets say, you have a local copy of the current puzzles in the phone, which are represented by some id or hash value. The app, in this webservice, would have then to send this data in the query to the server, which would then process this id, and compare to the latest one in the database. If it is different to the latest puzzle id, it can then send back the new puzzles that are available. Else, the server could then tell the application in the response that it is up to date.

Comment: I would use JSONs because i like them the most, but that is completely up to you.

Comment: Ya I am looking for the options and comparing . It's just I already know XML. That's why seeking for an advice. If JSON is better for it..I'm always willing to learn new things.

Comment: It is not actually better, I use JSONs because I find them more understandable. If you already know XML, it is a great choice too.

Comment: thank you.
So that's all I need to do ..?? 
get my data in XML. Create webservice and android people would be ready to go for their app. ??

Comment: Sure. you would still have to manage the database, but thats basically all you'd need. Just make sure the Android team know what data to send and receive. Organize yourselves and that's it, you'll be good to go.

Comment: Ya that's the basic lol..
thank you for the help. I guess thats just I needed to know.
Just a direction ...comment some nice links for tutorial or info on anything like this in case you can find.

thank you for your time.

Comment: If you are into books, try out Head First AJAX. or read about AJAX, thats pretty much what you're trying to do. Just change the Javascript for android or whatever platform youre developing on. This is a great place to start: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-g7vdk

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can transfer data through different applications/technology.
Some ways that appear to be straight ahead to me:

- The Android App can parse your generated HTML file directly and extract the questions and the options parsing the HTML tags.
- The Android App can also connect to your website DB and get the information directly from that.
- You can also expose your data creating a services using WebServices or ODATA, for example.

Comment: Webservices sounds better idea to me..

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I've only ever dealt with [Cordova](http://cordova.io) for writing apps but if Cordova can do it...

In the app I wrote for an internal application I used an AJAX call (Cordova uses JS + HTML as its interface). My PHP server then returned a response my app could use (in my case, JSON) It sounds like this is what you want to know. Now your app team will have to tell you what format to send your response but it's possible to have apps do this.